# Why my div is overlapping even I used white-space in my javascript slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I don't understand why the div is overlapping. I want my div to be exact I as I click next or back pages. Here is my code

```
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .slider-wrap {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: black;

        }
        .slider-main {
            white-space: nowrap;
            transition: ease 1000ms;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .item {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            background: red;
            display: inline-flex;
            position: relative;
        }
        .text {
            position: absolute;
            background: gray;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            color: white;
            font-size: 25px;
        }
        .btn {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .slider-prev,.slider-next {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 25px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="product">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="slider-wrap">
                <div class="slider-main">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="text">1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="text">2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="text">3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="text">4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="text">5</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="text">6</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="btn">
        <button class="slider-prev" > Prev </button>
        <button class="slider-next" > Next </button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        let sliderMain  = document.querySelector('.slider-main')
        let sliderPrev = document.querySelector('.slider-prev')
        let sliderNext = document.querySelector('.slider-next')
        let slidesLength = sliderMain.querySelectorAll('.item').length
        console.log(slidesLength)
        let activeSlideIndex = 0;
        sliderMain.style.left = `-${(slidesLength - 6) * 100}%`

        sliderPrev.addEventListener('click',() => changeSlide('prev'));
        sliderNext.addEventListener('click',() => changeSlide('next'));

        const changeSlide = dir => {
            // console.log(dir)
            if (dir == 'next') {
                activeSlideIndex--;
                if (activeSlideIndex < -slidesLength + 1) {
                    activeSlideIndex = 0;
                } 
            } else if (dir == "prev") {
                activeSlideIndex++;
                if (activeSlideIndex > 0) {
                    activeSlideIndex = -slidesLength + 1
                }
            }
            console.log(activeSlideIndex)
            sliderMain.style.left = `-${(slidesLength - 6 - activeSlideIndex) * 100}%`
        }

    </script>
```

My problem is that everythings alright in my javascript and html function but I don't know what's wrong with my css. I don't know if this is the result of my white-space: no-wrap which is giving a little space so that it will make increase the div margins. So anyone can help me about this? I want it to be normal with no overlapping in each click I do.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a display inline-table inside the slider-main class

```
.slider-main {
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: ease 1000ms;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: I already know that I don't know but I believe it has something issue with white-space too...that doesn't cooperate with left or translateX